# Transform dummy variable into categorical variable

Tags: r, dplyr, categorical-data, dummy-variable

Here is my dataframe

```
data<-data.frame(
ID=c(1:8),
Diag1=c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0),
Diag2=c(0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0),
Diag3=c(0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0),
Multiple.Diag=c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0)
)
```

I have patients with different diagnoses, some of them have multiple diagnoses. These diagnoses are dummy variables that need to be converted into categorical variables. If the patient has `Mult.diag==1`, his diagnosis will be `Multiple.diag`, otherwise his diagnosis will be either `Diag1`, `Diag2` or `Diag3`. If the patient has 0 for the whole variables, the diagnosis will be `"Other"`.

Here is what I want to have:

```
  ID     Diagnosis
1  1         Diag1
2  2         Diag2
3  3 Multiple.Diag
4  4 Multiple.Diag
5  5         Diag1
6  6         Diag3
7  7 Multiple.Diag
8  8         Other
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with tidyverse you could also do:

```
data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(which.max(as.integer(factor(name))*value))%>%
  mutate(name = if_else(value == 0, 'other',name), value= NULL)
 # A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   ID [8]
     ID name         
  <int> <chr>        
1     1 Diag1        
2     2 Diag2        
3     3 Multiple.Diag
4     4 Multiple.Diag
5     5 Diag1        
6     6 Diag3        
7     7 Multiple.Diag
8     8 other
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `max.col` to find the index of the column with the highest value in each row of subset of 'Diag' columns, use that index to get the column name, then change those elements to 'Multiple.Diag' where it is 1 and if there are no 1s in a row, we categorize it as 'Other' using a logical expression created with `rowSums`

-codes

```
out <- cbind(data['ID'], Diagnosis = names(data)[-1][
              max.col(data[startsWith(names(data), 'Diag')], 'first')])
i1 <- as.logical(data$Multiple.Diag)
out$Diagnosis[i1] <- 'Multiple.Diag'
i2 <- rowSums(data[-1]) == 0
out$Diagnosis[i2] <- 'Other'
```

-output

```
out
#  ID     Diagnosis
#1  1         Diag1
#2  2         Diag2
#3  3 Multiple.Diag
#4  4 Multiple.Diag
#5  5         Diag1
#6  6         Diag3
#7  7 Multiple.Diag
#8  8         Other
```

`max.col` is vectorized and should be very fast

---

Or another option is to use `which` with `arr.ind = TRUE`

```
m1 <- which(data[-1] == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
cbind(data['ID'], Diagnosis = ifelse(rowSums(data[-1]) == 0, 
    'Other', names(data)[-1][tapply(m1[, 2], m1[,1], FUN = max)]))
```

-output

```
#  ID     Diagnosis
#1  1         Diag1
#2  2         Diag2
#3  3 Multiple.Diag
#4  4 Multiple.Diag
#5  5         Diag1
#6  6         Diag3
#7  7 Multiple.Diag
#8  8         Other
```

---

Or using `tidyverse` using the same method

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   transmute(ID, Diagnosis = case_when(rowSums(.[-1]) == 0 ~ "Other", 
         TRUE ~ names(.)[-1][max.col(.[-1], 'last')]))
```

-output

```
#  ID     Diagnosis
#1  1         Diag1
#2  2         Diag2
#3  3 Multiple.Diag
#4  4 Multiple.Diag
#5  5         Diag1
#6  6         Diag3
#7  7 Multiple.Diag
#8  8         Other
```

---

Or another option where we use `rowwise` along with `c_across`

```
data %>%
   rowwise %>% 
   transmute(ID, Diagnosis = coalesce(case_when(as.logical(Multiple.Diag) 
    ~ 'Multiple.Diag',
     TRUE ~ names(.)[-1][as.logical(c_across(-1))][1] ), 'Other'))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Rowwise: 
#     ID Diagnosis    
#  <int> <chr>        
#1     1 Diag1        
#2     2 Diag2        
#3     3 Multiple.Diag
#4     4 Multiple.Diag
#5     5 Diag1        
#6     6 Diag3        
#7     7 Multiple.Diag
#8     8 Other
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply()` and built-in function like this. You can add the result to your original `data` or saving in a new dataframe. The function `myfunc` extract the name of the variable for treatment based on the directions you mentioned. Here the code:

```
#Code
myfunc <- function(x)
{
  y <- names(x)[max(which(x==1))]
  if(is.na(y))
  {
    y <- 'Others'
  }
  return(y)
}
#Add var
data$Var <- apply(data[,-1],1,myfunc)
```

Output:

```
  ID Diag1 Diag2 Diag3 Multiple.Diag           Var
1  1     1     0     0             0         Diag1
2  2     0     1     0             0         Diag2
3  3     1     0     0             1 Multiple.Diag
4  4     0     1     1             1 Multiple.Diag
5  5     1     0     0             0         Diag1
6  6     0     0     1             0         Diag3
7  7     1     1     1             1 Multiple.Diag
8  8     0     0     0             0        Others
```